# How can I get the latest version of Microsoft Build Tools 2013 onto my build server?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, build, msbuild, teamcity

MSBuild is now provided with Visual Studio and its versioning is aligned with Visual Studio. It is also provided as a standalone installer (Microsoft Build Tools 2013) as seen here: http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads

Due to a bugfix that Microsoft put out in Visual Studio 2013 Update 3, I am trying to find the equivalent build of MSBuild to install on the build server. The version of MSBuild referenced in the download link above is 12.0.21005.1, which equates to the initial version of VS2013.

I can't find anywhere with a version of the Microsoft Build Tools 2013 installer that has been built after Update 3 was released. The VS2013 Update 3 build number is 12.0.30723.0.

Does anyone know where to find this? Or is there an alternative method of copying an updated version of MSBuild from my dev machine (which has VS2013 Update 3) to the build server?

I do not want to install Visual Studio in full on the build server.

**Extra Information**

The reason I need VS2013 update 3 build tasks is because the SignFile task was updated to take a targetframeworkversion parameter which gets around a bug with signing ClickOnce apps. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164304.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one later version:

https://chocolatey.org/packages/microsoft-build-tools/12.0.21005.20140416

Microsoft Build Tools 2013 12.0.21005.20140416

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. VS2013 Update 3 was released on Aug 4 2014 and it looks like this was built in April 2014. The version number suggests it was built against VS2013 initial as well. I don't think this will help. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2933779

Comment: Send chocolatey the information.  They may update it.